# In which of the three topologies is $f(t)=(t, 2t, 3t, 4t, \ldots)$ continuous? Here, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement?

> Consider the product, uniform, and box topologies on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. In which of the three topologies is $f(t)=(t, 2t, 3t, 4t, \ldots)$ continuous? Here, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

(By a theorem in the textbook,) $f$ is continuous in the product topology, since each $f_k(t)=kt$ is continuous.

Consider the basis element $U = \displaystyle{\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)}$ of the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(U)$. Then, $f(x) \in U$. This implies that $|f_n(x)| < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This further implies that $|x| < \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, it must be the case that $x = 0$. But then, $f^{-1}(U) = \{0\}$, which is not open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f$ is not continuous in the box topology.

Now, let $0 < \epsilon < 1$, and let $B = B_\bar\rho(0, \epsilon)$ be a basis element for the uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. Suppose $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. Then, $f(x) \in B$. This implies that $\bar d(f(x_i), 0) < \epsilon$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\epsilon < 1$, we have $d(f_i(x), 0) < \epsilon$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that $|kx| < \epsilon$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that $x = 0$. Since $\{0\}$ is not open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is not continuous in the uniform topology.

Comment: The first two look good to me. I guess $\bar{d}(u,v) = \min(1, \sup_{n \in \omega} d(u_n, v_n))$? In this case the third proof is correct too.

Comment: Is $B_\rho(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^n$ ?

Comment: Note that since the box topology is finer than the uniform topology, once you know that $f$ is not continuous with respect to the uniform topology (and your proof of that is correct), you can immediately infer that it’s not continuous wrt the box topology, either.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think $\bar{d}(x,y) = \min\{|x-y|, 1\}$ and $\bar{\rho}(x,y)= \sup \{\bar{d}(x_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha}) : \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}.$

Comment: @StefanHamcke I think $B_{\bar{\rho}}(0,\epsilon) = \{y\in \mathbb{R}^{\omega} : \bar{\rho}(0,y) < \epsilon\}.$ The question is possibly from Munkres' Topology.